# How to acces user variables in mailgun template

Tags: node.js, mailgun

in node i  want to send a link containing a token inside a mailgun template but i cant access it inside the template

```
 const data = {

    from: '<support@support.com>',
    to: email,
    subject: 'password reset',
    "v:token": token,
    template: "password",

  };
```

in mailgun logs i can see that im receiving the token inside as

```
"user-variables": {
        "token": "afcd8b104527201ee7445f9a613b384b0fbc36b6"
    }
```

in the template i tried accesing it like %user-variables.token% with no luck

i need to be inside a link like https://host/passwordReset/token

Comment: This might help . It is already there on the documentation https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#batch-sending and look for the Recipient  Variable